# Oracle Apex - change chart label

Tags: sql, oracle, oracle-apex

I have a chart based on region classic report, with a column populated with number's associated to id's in a different table.

The chart shows the label like is inserted in the table(number), how can I show the representative name for the `ID` from the other table (text)?

[image]

[image: Graphic/ Chart labels]

Answer (score 2):

In the chart attributes, you can nominate which column in the SQL represents the label shown in the report.

```
select count(*) cnt
 ,emp label
 ,deptno series
from emp
group by emp, deptno
```

[image]

This is the behaviour in Oracle JET charts from 5.1

Comment: The label from the "master" table is only ID's, the name is on different table. I'm trying left join but the label still with values       

    select TIP_FECHO_2 LABEL
        ,count(*) VALOR
        from NVG_INCIDENTES
       left join NVG_TIP_FECHO ON (NVG_INCIDENTES.TIP_FECHO_2 = NVG_TIP_FECHO.NOME)
 where CI is not null
GROUP BY TIP_FECHO_2

Comment: Question resolved with:
   ` select NVG_TIP_FECHO.NOME as NOME2
,count(*) VALOR
 from NVG_TIP_FECHO NVG_TIP_FECHO,
    NVG_INCIDENTES NVG_INCIDENTES 
 where NVG_TIP_FECHO.ID(+) =NVG_INCIDENTES.TIP_FECHO_2 and CI is not null
 GROUP by NOME `